# is_deeply test ignoring array order?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I am looking for a test routine like `is_deeply` in [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Test-Simple-0.98/lib/Test/More.pm).
There's `cmp_bag` from [`Test::Deep`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Test-Deep-0.109/lib/Test/Deep.pm) but this only operates on the array itself, not the horribly large hash-of-arrays-of-hashes data structure I'm passing in. Is there something like:

```
is_deeply $got, $expected, {
    array => cmp_bag,
    # and other configuration...
}, "Ugly data structure should be the same, barring array order.";
```

**Clarification**

I could recursively delve into my `$expected` and `$got` objects and convert the arrays into bag objects:

```
sub bagIt {
    my $obj = shift;
    switch (ref($obj)) {
        case "ARRAY"    {
            return bag([
                map { $_ = bagIt($_) }
                @$obj
            ]);
        } case "HASH"   {
            return {
                map { $_ => bagIt( $obj->{$_} ) }
                keys %$obj
            };
        } else {
            return $obj;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell some variant of `is_deeply` to do this for me.

Comment: You could rewrite bagIt using [Data::Rmap](http://search.cpan.org/~bowmanbs/Data-Rmap-0.62/lib/Data/Rmap.pm), however I doubt extra dependency is worth several extra lines of code... I'd vote for bagIt if it was in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there isn't an option in [`Test::Deep`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Test-Deep-0.109/lib/Test/Deep.pm) or other `Test::*` packages to treat each array as a bag-set. The following function works, but is not efficient for testing over large data structures:

```
sub bagIt {
    my $obj = shift;
    my $ref = ref($obj);
    if ($ref eq 'ARRAY') {
        return Test::Deep::bag(
            map { $_ = bagIt($_) }
            @$obj
        );  
    } elsif ($ref eq 'HASH') {
        return {
            map { $_ => bagIt( $obj->{$_} ) } 
            keys %$obj
        };  
    } else {
        return $obj;
    }   
}
```

In the end, I ended up refactoring my code to not depend upon such a course-grained test.

Answer (score 3):

Well, from the [Test::Deep docs](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aDeep#bag-elements-),`cmp_bag(\@got, \@bag, $name)`is just shorthand for `cmp_deeply(\@got, bag(@bag), $name)`.

```
is_deeply( $got, {
    array => bag(qw/the values you expect/),
    # and other expected values
}, "Ugly data structure should be the same, barring array order." );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Updated the question to clarify. The issue is that I would have to walk over the data structure converting ARRAYs into bag objects manually. I'm wondering if there's some Test::* lib that would do this inline with comparing for deep equality.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `bagIt` function that you have written, you could always make a wrapper for `is_deeply` that applies `bagIt` for you:

```
sub is_deep_bag {
   splice @_, 1, 1, bagIt($_[1]); 
   goto &is_deeply  # magic goto so that errors are reported on the right line
}
```